# How to range the y axis of heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, heatmap

I created a heatmap by using the following data

```
weekdays    hours
0   6   22:00
1   6   22:00
2   0   06:00
3   0   10:00
4   0   10:00
... ... ...
153 1   12:00
154 1   12:00
155 1   12:00
156 1   12:00
157 1   12:00

ax = sns.heatmap(df.groupby([dfx.weekdays, dfx.hours]) # time_object
   ['date'].count()
   .rename_axis(index=['weekdays','hours'])
   .unstack(level=0)
)
```

[image]

and I want to rearrange the y axis like below heatmaps y axis, how can I do it

[image]